# Combobox checkbox display

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Just new in WPF, I'm trying to do a combobox that allows people to select the keywords, by checking them. Below is my XAML

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox Tag="{Binding Path=TagID}"
                      Content="{Binding Path=Tag}"
                      Margin="10,0,0,0"></CheckBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

the question is, how do I create a **custom display**? for example, the user selected three items. Instead of the selected item and the checkbox being displayed in the combo box text. I want the three selected items to be the ones displayed in the `combobox` text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [ItemContainerStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx) property which allows you to specify the container for your templates

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a multi-select combobox. I found this example here to be useful when creating one:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1a81c5/multi-select-combobox-in-wpf/

Apologies for not adding code but this article is pretty comprehensive!